# UIViewController inheritance: Passing parameters to a parent class that is a subclass of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app to quiz users on anatomy. I created a QuizControl class that is a subclass of UIViewController that uses a "Questions" structure to outline my needs. It creates a generic template that looks something like this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/171o4.png). It's a generic outline with a question label with 4 buttons underneath corresponding to the different answer choices.

My issue is that I want to keep this QuizControl class generic if possible and have other classes inherit it while only passing its array of questions back to the QuizControl class. I'm not understanding how to pass the parameter back to the class viewDidLoad() constructor.

Here is my [QuizControl class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0NYK.png) that is a subclass of UIViewControl.
And here is it's child: [TorsoQuiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkG7A.png)

---

If you can't see the pictures, the code looks like this:

**QuizControl**

```
struct Question {
    var Question : String!
    var Answers : [String]!
    var Answer : Int!
}

class QuizControl: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var QLabel: UILabel!

var Questions = [Question]()
var QNumber = Int()
var AnswerNumber = Int()
var correct = Int()
var incorrect = Int()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    Questions = [Question(Question: "Question 1", Answers: ["Answer 0","Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3"], Answer: 2),
                 Question(Question: "Question 2", Answers: ["Answer 4","Answer 5","Answer 6","Answer 7"], Answer: 0),
                 Question(Question: "Question 3", Answers: ["Answer 8","Answer 9","Answer 10","Answer 11"], Answer: 1),
                 Question(Question: "Question 4", Answers: ["Answer 12","Answer 13","Answer 14","Answer 15"], Answer: 2),
                 Question(Question: "Question 5", Answers: ["Answer 16","Answer 17","Answer 18","Answer 19"], Answer: 3),]
    pickQuestion()
}
```

**TorsoQuiz**

```
class TorsoQuiz: QuizControl {

var torsoQuestions = [Question(Question: "My chest hurts and I'm having difficulty breathing", Answers: ["Check for Asthma","Check family history of heart problems","Call an ambulance","Sample diagnosis 3"], Answer: 2),
Question(Question: "Question 2", Answers: ["Answer 4","Answer 5","Answer 6","Answer 7"], Answer: 0),
Question(Question: "Question 3", Answers: ["Answer 8","Answer 9","Answer 10","Answer 11"], Answer: 1),
Question(Question: "Question 4", Answers: ["Answer 12","Answer 13","Answer 14","Answer 15"], Answer: 2),
Question(Question: "Question 5", Answers: ["Answer 16","Answer 17","Answer 18","Answer 19"], Answer: 3),]
//Pass these questions/answers to Quiz Control?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

How do I go about passing parameters back to QuizControl?
The answers that I've seen already use .init() and .init()? but since the answers are old, the solutions aren't working on Xcode 10.2.1 and swift 5. The solutions use a frame: parameter that the compiler will not accept. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, it seems like an inheritance problem. Off the top of my head can think of two solutions.

I'd say the easiest solution would be to take advantage of the inherited `Questions` property. (By the way, properties/variables in swift should be [lowerCamelCased](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions).) So in the `TorsoQuiz` controller, before the call to `super.viewDidLoad()` just assign `Questions` to be equal to torsoQuestions.

However, another appropriate solution would be to use dependency injection to insert a class that manages the questions based on the area of the body. You could set up a protocol such as `QuestionManager` with method `getQuestion` and inject an implementation of it into the class before the view controller is loaded. It may be a little advanced for what you need, but it could make scaling (and testing) a lot easier.

Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/dependency-injection-in-swift-87c748a167be) on dependency injection that I haven't personally read but looks decent.

Good luck, and please comment with any more questions if this wasn't clear.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be rude or criticise your question, but looks like you need to improve your general understanding in Computer Programming before building a not so simple app like this. 
My opinion is that you are missing some crucial concept in Object Oriented Programming and Cocoa Touch/Swift.
I recommend this course for bootstrapping your programming career.
[hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read)

Happy coding!